# Extract from Except

Tags: haskell

I have this situation:

```
import Control.Monad.Except

data Foo = Foo { i :: Int }
data Bar = Bar { i :: Int , v: Char }

emptyFoo = Foo 0
emptyBar = Bar 0 'N'

extractF :: (Except String Foo) -> Foo
extractF ex = either (const emptyFoo) id (runExcept ex)

extractB :: (Except String Bar) -> Bar
extractB ex = either (const emptyBar) id (runExcept ex)
```

Is there a way to generalise the `extract` functions above in one only like:

```
myfoo = extract someFooInstanceWrappedInException
mybar = extract someBarInstanceWrappedInException
```

?

Comment: What would that use for the "empty" case? You have to pass it somehow, either by an explicit parameter or a typeclass dictionary.

Comment: the empty cases are only there to "fill" the either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare a class that provides the defaults

```
-- Note: consider using Data.Default instead of creating your own class.
class Default a where
    def :: a

instance Default Foo where
    def = Foo 0

instance Default Bar where
    def = Bar 0 'N'

extract :: Default a => Except String a -> a
extract ex = either (const def) id (runExcept ex)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `Except e` is an instance of [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable), you can define [`Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid) instances for your types and use [`fold :: (Foldable f, Monoid m) => f m -> m`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold).

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Data.Monoid

newtype Foo = Foo { getFoo :: Sum Int } deriving Monoid

extractFoo :: Except e Foo -> Foo
extractFoo = fold
```

I don't know what your types mean, exactly, so I just gave an example using `Sum`. The correct semantics for the `Monoid` instance would be domain-specific (and your types may not even be valid `Monoid`s). But the idea is that `mempty` would be your default value; since `Except e m` contains either zero or one `m`s, `fold` will plug in the default value if it's empty.

Comment: Thank you, it is very interesting. At the moment the types are not meant to be "summed" (maybe in the future) but I really like the idea.